# Configure KafkaAvroSerializer for transform step of topology

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I'm using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams Binder version 3.2.4, Confluent Platform ver 7.1.1. I following the documentation provided here `https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html`.

The Serde implementations for both the Key and Value are SpecificAvroSerde. The SpecificAvroSerde is configured to set auto_register_schemas = false because the topic has an union schema with schema references.
The stream is throwing a serialization error after the transform step in the topology as it cannot find registered schemas for the records in the schema registry.

edit: We are using multiple event types in a single topic. Confluent guidelines says to disable auto-schema registration for this topic. https://www.confluent.io/blog/multiple-event-types-in-the-same-kafka-topic/. We have disabled auto-schema-registration and registered the schema for the our main topic. However, after the transform step there's an new internal repartition topic is being created that doesn't have the registered schemas connected to it.

`Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException: Subject 'utw-local-095515-t-tipsProcess-repartition-value' not found.; error code: 40401`

```
  @Bean
    @Autowired
    public Consumer<KStream<UnreportedTipsKey, SpecificRecord>> tipsProcess(
            @Value("${kafka.store.tips}") String unreportedTipsStore,
            Serde<UnreportedTipsKey> tipsKeySerde, Serde<SpecificRecord> specificSerde,
            EventPersister eventPersister, @Value("${kafka.topic.tips}") String topic,
            TransformerSupplier<UnreportedTipsKey, SpecificRecord, KeyValue<UnreportedTipsKey, SpecificRecord>> tipsTransformerSupplier,
            @Value("${MDE_DEPLOYMENT_STAGE}") String env) {

        return input -> input.transform(tipsTransformerSupplier)
                .groupByKey(Grouped.with(tipsKeySerde, specificSerde))
                .aggregate(UnreportedTips::new,
                        new UnreportedTipsAggregator(
                                eventPersister, topic, env),
                        Materialized
                                .<UnreportedTipsKey, UnreportedTips, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(
                                        unreportedTipsStore)
                                .withKeySerde(tipsKeySerde).withValueSerde(
                                        SerdeConfiguration.unreportedTipsSerde()));
    }
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class SerdeConfiguration {

    private static final String SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG = "schema.registry.url";
    private static final String AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS = "auto.register.schemas";

    @Bean
    public Serde<UnreportedTipsKey> tipsKeySerde(
            @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url}") String schemaRegistryUrl) {

        final Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
        serdeConfig.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
        serdeConfig.put(AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, false);

        final Serde<UnreportedTipsKey> keySpecificRecordSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
        keySpecificRecordSerde.configure(serdeConfig, true);

        return keySpecificRecordSerde;
    }

    @Bean
    public Serde<SpecificRecord> specificRecordValueSerde(
            @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url}") String schemaRegistryUrl) {

        final Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
        serdeConfig.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
        serdeConfig.put(AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, false);

        final Serde<SpecificRecord> specificRecordValueSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
        specificRecordValueSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

        return specificRecordValueSerde;

    }

    public static Serde<UnreportedTips> unreportedTipsSerde() {
        Serdes.String();
        return new JsonSerde<>(new ObjectMapper().constructType(UnreportedTips.class));
    }
}
```

I have tried several solutions

- I wrote my own serializer that ignore the schema registry and set with the properties
  `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.tipsProcess.producer.keySerde`
  `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.bindings.tipsProcess.producer.valueSerde`
  Both of these properties were ignored and a KafkaAvroSerde is being configured.
- I updated the Serde in my configuration to use RecordNameStrategy:
  This doesn't work either because there's a different Serde being configured for the transform step.

```
  @Bean
    public Serde<SpecificRecord> specificRecordValueSerde(
            @Value("${spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url}") String schemaRegistryUrl) {

        final Map<String, Object> serdeConfig = new HashMap<>();
        serdeConfig.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
        serdeConfig.put(AUTO_REGISTER_SCHEMAS, false);
        serdeConfig.put("value.subject.name.strategy", RecordNameStrategy.class);

        final Serde<SpecificRecord> specificRecordValueSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
        specificRecordValueSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);

        return specificRecordValueSerde;

    }
```

The documentation says the following:

> Value serdes are inferred using the same rules used for inbound deserialization. First it matches to see if the outbound type is from a provided bean in the application. If not, it checks to see if it matches with a Serde exposed by Kafka such as - Integer, Long, Short, Double, Float, byte[], UUID and String. If that doesnt’t work, then it falls back to JsonSerde provided by the Spring Kafka project, but first look at the default Serde configuration to see if there is a match. Keep in mind that all these happen transparently to the application. If none of these work, then the user has to provide the Serde to use by configuration.

I realize that this may not apply to my topology because the function does not have a declared out bound stream, but the documentation does not mention how to configure serde for any intermediate topics.

Comment: References should not stop auto registration. You will need to actually register the schema if you don't want to get a "not found" error. That has little to do with Spring config

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @OneCricketeer I left out some information. The source topic does is registered with schemas. After the transform step there's a new internal repartition topic that lacks schemas.

Comment: You'll need to explicitly set the serde for the repartition function. https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Repartitioned.html

Comment: I have searched the documentation, but I do not see how to provide the serde for the repartition function via code or properties. May you point me in the right direction ?